# Recursion returns parent but not child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting to learn React and do not understand, why it works like this? I expect get element with `name:'Node2'`, but I get parent with `name:'Node1'`. I have some tree

```
jsonNodes: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'Node1',
                nodes: [
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Node2',
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                name: 'Node5',
                                nodes: null,
                            }],
                    }, {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'Node4',
                        nodes: null,
                    }],
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Node3',
                nodes: null,
            }]
```

and some recursion method

```
getSelectedNode(nodes) {
        return nodes.find(element => {
            if (element.name == this.state.selectedItem)
            {
                return element;
            }
            else if (element.nodes != null)
            {
                return this.getSelectedNode(element.nodes);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: `find` finds only an element of the actual array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using find properly. If you return anything truthy in its callback, it will return the current element.

`this.getSelectedNode(element.nodes)` will eventually return the right element, but it will be treated as a truthy value, and it will mean that no matter what you do, the first element will be returned if any of it's descendants it's a match.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
getSelectedNode(nodes) {
  // Use a for loop instead of forEach to avoid nested functions
  // Otherwise "return" will not work properly
  for (const element of nodes) {
    // Check if this element is the seleted one, return it if it is
    if(element.name === this.state.selectedItem) {
       return element
    }

    // If it's not - recursively check its descendants, if it has any
    if(element.nodes){
      const found =  this.getSelectedNode(element.nodes)

      if(found){
       return found
      }
    }
  }

  // didn't find anything, return null
  return null
}
```

Comment: I was hoping this could be done built-in functionality. Thank you